# How should I convert it to the real number?

Tags: algorithm, function, class

I tried both **str** and **repr**. but both of them doesn't work and still return <**main**.UnorderedList object at 0x10cefccc0> these things.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = UnorderedList()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.items)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

    def size(self):
        length = self.items.size()
        count = 0
        for i in range(0, length):

            count += 1
        return count


print(stack_list.__repr__())
```

result is:
[<**main**.Node object at 0x10db27c18>, <**main**.Node object at 0x10db27d30>]

Comment: Well, what _do_ you expect as output?

Comment: the indexes in the Unordered list

Comment: I think you don't want the indexes (indices) of the unordered list as these will be the numbers 0 to len(list) - 1.  I guess instead you want the _elements_ of this list, right?

Comment: Yes, I have already figured out how to print out my peek. But still having trouble to convert the strings to the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in getting the output you wrote after "result is" then (your question is a bit unclear and) you can use this code:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '[ %s ]' % ', '.join(repr(item) for item in self.items)
```

The `__repr__()` function is supposed to return a representation of the object, though, which should recreate the object again when interpreted.  So consider this instead:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = UnorderedList(items)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Stack([ %s ])' % ', '.join(repr(item) for item in self.items)
```

This will produce `repr` output  like `Stack([ "foo", "bar" ])`.

I find it peculiar, though, that you program a *stack* which is based on an *unordered* list.  This is confusing and I would not recommend to do that in the first place.  Normally, stacks have a fixed order of their items.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mollyhuang/PycharmProjects/ECS 32B HW 2 test.py/venv/P2 stack abstract data.py", line 192, in <module>
    print(stack_list.__repr__())
  File "/Users/mollyhuang/PycharmProjects/ECS 32B HW 2 test.py/venv/P2 stack abstract data.py", line 143, in __repr__
    return 'Stack([ %s ])' % ', '.join(repr(item) for item in self.items)
TypeError: 'UnorderedList' object is not iterable
3

Comment: »'UnorderedList' object is not iterable« — are you kidding me?  What kind of weird list are you using there that one cannot iterate it‽

Comment: Okay, wait.  I cannot figure out how to use the `UnorderedList` you are using, it is no builtin or standard library type.  Try that with a `list` instead and it will work.  Try to figure out how this `UnorderedList` can be iterated and use that instead of the simple `in self.items` that I used.

Comment: ，the unordered_list was given. I can not use the normal built-in list.

Comment: Try to figure out how this UnorderedList can be iterated.